# Is there a metod to have a trash can in Plone?

Tags: python, plone, plone-4.x

I want to give at all members of a Plone (4.3.7) site the possibility to restore a file accidentally deleted.
I only found ecreall.trashcan for this purpose, but I've some problem with installation. After add it in buildout.conf and do a bin/buildout the output contain some error like...

> File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/ecreall/trashcan/skins/ecreall_trashcan_templates/isTrashcanOpened.py", line 11
>       return session and session.get('trashcan', False) or False
>   SyntaxError: 'return' outside function
>
> File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/ecreall/trashcan/skins/ecreall_trashcan_templates/object_trash.py", line 23
>       return context.translate(msg)
>   SyntaxError: 'return' outside function
>
> File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/ecreall/trashcan/skins/ecreall_trashcan_templates/object_restore.py", line 23
>       return context.translate(msg)
>   SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

...

And so, I don't find any new add-on to enable or configure in site setup.

Someone know what could be, or is there another method for do what I want?
Please.... thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Output like "return outside funtion" is [harmless during install](https://plone.org/documentation/error/syntaxerror-return-outside-function), the compiler thinks it needs to compile scripts that will only be run inside Plone later on (where it's inside a function, but the compiler doesn't know that).

On experimentation, it appears that Trashcan needs a zcml slug, i.e. in your buildout.cfg, in the `[buildout]` section, extend the `zcml` phrase:

```
############################################
# ZCML Slugs
# ----------
# Some eggs need ZCML slugs to tell Zope to
# use them. This is increasingly rare.

zcml =
    ecreall.trashcan
    (further lines)
```

At least, then it shows up in the ZMI quickinstaller, I'v enot investigated any further.

Comment: OK, understand... Thankyou! At this point the problem is: where I enable this add-on, where is?

Comment: After installing it in the quickinstaller (or possibly through the control panel > addons), you'll find "move to trashcan" in the actions menu, (or "restore", if the page is already there), and there will be a trashcan icon in the content area to take you to the trashcan. It doesn't appear to have a configuration panel in the add-ons section.

Comment: As you suggest Ulrich, I've inserted ecreall.trash can under zcml. After that the plug-in appears in Addons panel and I've enabled it.
Ok, now there is a little trashcan icon, but also many problems. A content may again be deleted, and it not go inside the trashcan, I must use the function -move to trashcan. I have to click 2 times in the icon for go inside or outside the trashcan, and also when I think to be exited it reappear when I navigate in the other folders or returned in the first. The content of these don't display to me and a message warn that I'm again inside the trash can :(

Answer (score 2):

If you don't find a proper add-on, know that in Plone a trash can only be a matter of workflow.
You can customize your workflow adding a new *trash* transition that move the content in a state (*trashed*) where users can't see it (maybe keep the visibility open for Manager and/or Site Administrators).

Probably you must also customize the `content_status_modify` script because after the trash on a content you must be redirected to another location (or you'll get an Unhautorized error).

Comment: Thanks keul, but I want to give the possibility to restore the content to the user who has deleted it

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution(!!!) working with -Content Rules- in the control panel.
First I've created a folder called TRASHCAN , after in content rule I've added a rule that copy the file/page/image in folder trashcan if it will be removed.
This rule can be disable in trashcan folder, so you could delete definitely the objects inside.

Comment: Nice solution! I see only an issue: if you *copy* the content inside the trashcan on deletion, the later you'll restore it, it's in fact a different object: you loose content history, relations  and probably also internal links.

Comment: Interesting discovery keul. 
I noticed another thing, very important ... When I go into Contents, and delete something (selected the object and pressed delete) its go in the trash folder, but if I open one element and select the action delete, this does not go in the trash... I don't know why...

Answer (score 1):

[adi.trash](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/adi.trash) might be what you're looking for. The usual disclaimer: Io sono authorista.

Comment: @fabiosko: Thanks, of course I'm curious about your experience with it :-)